# Does this vector equation have a solution

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am working with a modified version of the Lorentz force equation wherein I am trying to find generalized E and B field components that produce a specific particle path. I have replaced E with $$\vec{E}=\frac{\vec{v} ^{2}}{2\vec{r}}$$ so my only unknowns are the x,y,z components of the B field.

I want to solve the following equation now for Bx, By, and Bz where a,v, r (and E) are known. 
$$
\vec{a} = \vec{E}+\vec{v}\times \vec{B}
$$

I am not sure if the following matrix can be used to solve this equation, but, if it is, it doesn't seem to have a solution. (due to the 0 determinant). I figured that there would be a solution because there are three unknowns (Bx, By, Bz) and three equations, but I am trouble proving this.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 0& -v_{z} &v_{y} \\ 
 v_{z}&0  &-v_{x} \\ 
 -v_{y}&  v_{x}& 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
B_{x}\\ 
B_{y}\\ 
B_{z}
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
a_{x}-E_{x}\\a_{y}-E_{y} 
\\ a_{z}-E_{z}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So mainly I want to know if the matrix I have set up represents the equation above it and if a solution for the B components can be achieved.

Comment: You cannot divide by a vector, also by $\vec v^2$ do you mean $v \times v$ or $v . v$?

Comment: I don't know about your specific problem, but generally working with Lorentz' equation I found it gets very easy if you just rotate coordinates so that $B_z = 0$, and then you're left with the easier equation in the plane (in the $z$-axis it's just a simple parabola than). You can rotate backwards after you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

The cross product $\vec{v}\times$ is indeed not invertible, due to the fact that it has a non-trivial nullspace (all vectors parallel to $\vec{v}$).

There are thus two possibilities:

- $\vec{a}-\vec{E}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{v}$: a solution exists where the components of $\vec{B}$ perpendicular to $\vec{v}$ are uniquely specified but the component of $\vec{B}$ parallel to $\vec{v}$ is arbitrary.
- $\vec{a}-\vec{E}$ is not perpendicular to $\vec{v}$: your equation is a contradiction, no solution exists.

Comment: In the first line it will be more accurate if you said 'non-trivial nullspace'. Nice and clear solution! (+1)

Comment: Thanks! So how would I implement the orthogonality between the a-E and v terms into my set of equations?